# Sorting comparator in c++

Tags: c++, sorting, c++14, comparator

I have to sort strings by their length. Eg:
Input: "Keep calm and code on"
Expected Output: "On and keep calm code"

First Comparator is:   return s1.length()<=s2.length();
Output : "On and code calm keep"

Second Comparator is : return s1.length()<s2.length();

Output :  "On and keep calm code"

How output changes with change of equality in both comparators. I am confused how comparator function works internally.

Comment: Please read carefully the description of the predicate as well, `<=` is _not_ suitable as general comparator for STL-style sorting algorithms that need a strict-weak ordering. As a new user, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Rather than jumbling all the input together then sorting it, you could create an array up to some maximum word size (or a vector and expand it whenever you get a longer word), or use a map keyed on size, and store vectors or lists of words of specific lengths.  More efficient.

Answer (score 3):

use [std::stable_sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort). It doesn't change order of equal elements.

```
std::vector<std::string> vec = { "Keep" , "calm",  "and", "code", "on" };
std::stable_sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2) { return s1.size() < s2.size(); });
for (const auto& v : vec) {
    std::cout << v << std::endl;
}

Output:
on
and
Keep
calm
code
```